# accessing OCaml hierarchical modules

Tags: module, ocaml

There are submodules in the module [Stdlib](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Stdlib.html). How can I access them? For example, the natural `Stdlib.Fun.id` causes

```
Error: Unbound module Stdlib.Fun
```

There are a lot of tutorials on OCaml module system, but they all consider only one level of hierarchy. At least, I did not found otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access them exactly like that. The error message says that `Stdlib.Fun` does not exist. `Stdlib.Fun` was added in [4.08](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.08.0.html), and `Stdlib` itself was added in [4.07](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.07.0.html) (before that you could only reference the standard library modules directly). Therefore, if you use a version of OCaml older than 4.08, this specific invocation won't work.

At time of writing, the latest version of the compiler is [4.10](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.10.0.html). You might want to upgrade to that to avoid further surprises like this.